# PHP form processing

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I have a html form which has 2 textbox and a text area. I am fetching the data from the form using a php code to display it on another page.

html form code:

```
    <html>

<form name="addsg" method="POST" action="validate.php">

<div class="label">name</div>
<div class="response"><span><textarea class="textarea" name="name"></textarea></span></div>


<div class="label">age</div>
<div class="response"><span><input class="textbox" name="age" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" value="" /></span></div>


<div class="label">place</div>
<div class="response"><span><input class="textbox" name="place" type="text" value="" /></span></div>

<div class="submit_section button">
<input id="generate" type="submit"  name="script" value="generate" />
</div>

</form>
</html>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

    if (!empty($_POST['name']) 
    && !empty($_POST['age'])
    && !empty($_POST['place']))

   {
 echo '<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="100" rows="5" readonly>';

      echo "{$_POST['name']},{$_POST['age']} years old, from {$_POST['place']}";
     echo '</textarea>';
   }
 ?>
```

If I put only one name in name text area column, I will get output like this

```
anoop,26 years old, from IN
```

But if I put more than one name in the name column(with same age and place), output showing like this

```
anoop
Tom,26 years old, from IN
```

Age and place are showing only for one name, not for all.
I would like to get output like this

```
 anoop,26 years old, from IN
 Tom,26 years old, from IN
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: I tried to come up with something with no success. However the following link will help you achieve your goal, am sure. http://www.tizag.com/phpT/foreach.php

Comment: You're welcome. You should post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?
$name_array = explode( "\n", $_POST['name'] ); //use the new line char as the separator
?>

<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="100" rows="5" readonly>
<?
foreach( $name as $name_array )
  echo $name.', '.$_POST['age'].' years old, from '.$_POST['age']."<br/>\n";
?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: this is not working giving syntax error foreach statement I changed it like this `$name_array = explode( "\n", $_POST['name'] ); //use the new line char as the separator
   
 foreach ($name_array as $name)
echo $name.', '.$_POST['age'].' years old, from '.$_POST['place']."\n";
   
   ?>`  only problem with this is no break between each line. all showing as single line `anoop , 25 years old, from abc tom, 25 years old, from abc`

Comment: Inside the text area "\n" should start a new line. Make sure you are using double quotes and not single quotes. Outside the text area it sould be a <br />.

Answer (score 0):

You can put multiple textbox for name and declare name as array .

for example:

```
<input type="text" name="ex[]" id="ex"/>
<input type="text" name="ex[]" id="ex1"/>
```

PHP:

```
for($1=0;$i<count($_POST['ex']);$i++){

echo $_POST['ex'][$i];

}
```

Comment: putting multiple text box is not possible here, sometime it might have more than 50 names.I need to process this within one textarea (one line contain only one name)

Comment: @user1128648 I edited the answer for Maha. Seems like he didn't indent his code properly. See if that will help you.

Comment: @ Fred : putting multiple textbox not possible in this case. user will be adding only one name in one line. so I am trying to take each line as separate entries.

Comment: @user1128648 I'm confused. First off, why do you have the `name` field as a `<textarea>` instead of an `<input>`? Your question is starting to no longer make sense. Do you want users to enter their name (as a single entry), then their age and location, and have the results appear one underneath each other **"saved in a FILE"**, or do you want it to just output in your `textarea` box and `explode` each item as an `array`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, that should work out.

```
<?
$lines = array();
$names = explode("\n", $_POST['name']);

foreach($names as $name)
  $lines[] = $name.', '.$_POST['age'].' years old, from '.$_POST['age'];
?>

<html>
<body>
<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="100" rows="5" readonly>
<?php implode("\n", $lines); ?>
</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @FalkS. I for one, tried your edited answer, and when I tested it, returned a textarea box only, with no data entered from the form.

Comment: @FalkS. Ok, I added an `echo` for the names and both names are not underneath each other, but still one beside each other.

Comment: yeah sorry i forgot the echo. Try to replace "\n" with PHP_EOL (as glue for the implode)

Answer (score 0):

try to use these two function with order : 
 1- nl2br($_POST['name'])
 2- strip_tags()

maybe some hidden html tags is causing that